# Share a function between two passes inside CG Shader for unity3d

Tags: unity, shaders, cg, architecture

I'm writing a shader in CG language for Unity3d. 
When making transparent object you need to create two similar passes in SubShader. First to render only back faces (with `Cull Front`) and second to render only front faces  (with `Cull Back`). But the code for vertex and fragment function is the same.

Is it possible not to double a code and declare some functions, that would be shared between passes?
I want to have something like in my code example.

```
Shader "cool shader" {
Properties {
    ...
}
SubShader {

    CGPROGRAM
    // need to declare vertexOutput somewhow here
    float4 sharedFragFoo(vertexOutput i) : COLOR  // How to make smth like this?
    {
        ....
        return float4(...);
    }
    ENDCG

    pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v) {
            vertexOutput o;     
            ...
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : COLOR
        {
            return sharedFragFoo(i); // call the shared between passes function
        }

        ENDCG
    }

    pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        vertexOutput vert(vertexInput v) {
            vertexOutput o;
            ...
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(vertexOutput i) : COLOR
        {
            return sharedFragFoo(i); // call the shared between passes function
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the #include directive? I use that to share functions from Unity's libraries all the time, so presumably it could be used with custom files (not making this an answer because I haven't confirmed it works, or details of where to put the .cginc file)

Answer (score 1):

We can define all that lies between `CGPROGRAM` and `ENDCG` in separate ***.cginc** file and include it inside each pass.

For details look 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530184/1351629 .

Sorry for the cross-post. 
I have found out how to do it using includes and posted the answer on SO.